# inserting a new value to mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$current_new_ip = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip_table VALUES ('1','".$current_new_ip."', '1')");
```

mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE ip_table (                                 
            id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                   
            ip_number int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
            used int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
          )
```

actually, ip is : 56.78.123.90

however these php codes are inserting: 5678

i wanna insert ip as 56.78.123.90, how can i do it?

Comment: What's the field type of your IP field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ip_number` column's type to `varchar(15)` - because your IP address is a string - not an integer.

```
CREATE TABLE ip_table (                                 
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                   
        ip_number varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
        used int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
      )
```

Comment: Downvote: IP address **is** an integer, not a string. And to be precisely: IPv4 - 32-bit integer, IPv6 - 128-bit integer.

Comment: But as I said: HIS IP address here is a string here. Read carefully mate. ;)

Comment: Another option would be to leave the field definition as-is and do `INSERT ... inet_ntoa('$ip') ...`, assuming only v4 IPs will be used.

Answer (score 1):

ip_number must be a varchar(15), not a integer ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep in mind that IPv4 (32-bit) will be replaced by IPv6 (128-bit) so using INT type (32-bit long) might cause some problems in near feature.
2. Use [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) functions to convert from number to text